# Is white vinegar as effective against black mold as rice or apple vinegar?

Tags: windows, cleaning, mold

Does anyone know if you can use white vinegar to irradiate black mold from inside window panes? I see they mention rice vinegar or apple cider vinegar; is there a difference on how those react with mold spores versus white vinegar? I'm trying to stick with a more natural approach since I have a chemical sensitivity.

Comment: _" I see they mention..."_ Who mentions?

Answer (score 1):

The rationale for using vinegar in treating mold is that the acidity disrupts the pH balance that it needs for growth.  Black mold's [growth range runs between a pH of 4 and 7](http://www.moldbacteriaconsulting.com/fungi/how-fast-does-mould-grow-on-building.html).  Different vinegars will have [different pH values that run between 2.4 and 3.4](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/food-ph-d_403.html), so the vinegar with the lowest pH would presumably be the most effective (although lemon juice or a citric acid solution would be even better).  However - the other consideration is that upsetting the pH balance only *slows* (albeit pretty dramatically) fungal growth, so I'd actually go with a distilled vinegar personally - cider vinegars contain some solids and unconverted sugars that would potentially provide a food source.

Note that you can go the *other way* with pH and use a base instead of an acid. A saturated solution of baking soda in water will have a pH of somewhere around 8.1, so it should be effective via the same mechanism.

Finally, you can *mix* baking soda and vinegar and use that on molds instead, although this would not be using a pH vector - it would be using an oxidizer to disrupt growth.

Comment: Interesting but wouldn't the vinegar and baking soda just neutralize each other? I am not understanding the oxidizer reference.

Comment: @ArchonOSX - As far as pH goes, yes.  But... like the grade school science project volcano, it generates a bunch of CO2 and attacks it through oxidation.

Comment: Ahh ok better living through chemistry.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've been using cheap white vinegar which contains water, so when I spray the bathroom mould on walls & ceiling, just realised I've been been simultaneously slowing it's growth, and feeding it, as does any treatment that contains water. Am about to tackle the mould using distilled white wine vinegar 6% acidity & fresh lemon juice. Will post results :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Any vinegar you can buy will have water in it, and water doesn't "feed" mold, it just encourages it until the water has evaporated.